# Why can't I validate a JComponent?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jcomponent

From [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#validate%28%29):

> `public void validate()`
>
> Validates this container and all of its subcomponents. Validating a container means laying out its subcomponents.

That is what I want to do. With an as lightweight component as possible. But when I do this whith a `JComponent` a call to `validate()` doesn't make the component "valid".

```
    JComponent c = new JComponent() {};
    System.out.println(c.isValid()); // false
    c.validate();
    System.out.println(c.isValid()); // false
```

Why can't I make a `JComponent` valid?

Comment: please look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8330828/714968 +1

Comment: @mKorbel: That answer didn't explain anything to me.

Comment: put there isValid & getSize & Whatever

Comment: @mKorbel: What? I don't understand what you are trying to say. Chris seem to be right that you need a Top-Level Container to be able to use `validate()`, otherwise it does **nothing** when I call it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the docs for [`isValid()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isValid%28%29) it says:

> A component is valid when it is correctly sized and positioned within its parent container and all its children are also valid.

This is the case until you reach a [Top-Level Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html#general%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B) (`JFrame`, `JInternalFrame` or `JApplet`). In the example you have in your question, your `JComponent` doesn't have a parent so it can never be valid.

Comment: But `JComponent` **is** a `Container` and if a parent is always needed, then infinitly many containers is needed.

Comment: Yes it is a container, but it has to have a parent until you get to a TopLevelContainer (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html#general).

Comment: Ok, thanks. That was bad :( You should add that to your answer.

Comment: However, `validate()` should work, since it only layouts it's subcomponents, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The Javadoc for `java.awt.Component.isValid()` states:

> A component is valid when it is correctly sized and positioned within its parent container and all its children are also valid.

In short, you can't validate the component until it has been added to a container.

Comment: `JComponent` **is** a `Container`.

Answer (score 0):

To add up to what has been said in the answers, don't forget to override `getPreferedSize()` method to return your component preferred size. Otherwise the layout manager  won't position your `JComponent` hence will not be displayed.