# java resizing methods

Tags: java, swing, methods, resize, jcomponent

Could you tell me what methods are called upon a JFrame/JDialog after you resize it manually?
( after you resize it using the mouse cursor, while the frame is visible on the screen). I noticed that my JDialog is not valid eventhough I call `validate()` or `revalidate()` upon it, but after I resize it a bit, my frame becomes valid.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "frame becomes valid"? Also if you can provide sscce

Comment: As I see you would like to make your JDialog be valid as it becomes valid after resize. Look at this thread about validating o JComponent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362484/why-cant-i-validate-a-jcomponent

Comment: Becomes vaild means that the frame.isValid() returns true ... I don't think this is so ambiguous.

Comment: sounds like something is wrong with the code you are not showing ... usually, validation is handled automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is [java.awt.event.ComponentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html)

> The listener interface for receiving component events. When the
>   component's size, location, or visibility changes, the relevant method
>   in the listener object is invoked, and the ComponentEvent is passed to
>   it.

For example:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements ComponentListener {

    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        // re compute?
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't be necessary ... usually repaints are handled automatically if necessary

Answer (score 0):

With this code I am able to resize the width, height of 3 tables.

```
container.addControlListener(new ControlAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void controlResized(ControlEvent e) {
                tableJobs.setBounds(20, 143,container.getBounds().width-40, container.getBounds().height-20);
                tableMessages.setBounds(20, 143,container.getBounds().width-40, container.getBounds().height-20);
                tableSplfs.setBounds(20, 143,container.getBounds().width-40, container.getBounds().height-20);
            }
        });
```